# hibernate @formula select only field

Tags: hibernate

I am following a tutorial on hibernate and have a field on the entity that should be select only. However, upon save of entity the filed is in the insert query and ending up on error. Please assist.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="finances_user")
@Access(value=AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class User {

    ...
    private Date birthDate;

    @Formula("lower(datediff(curdate(), birth_date)/365)")
    private int age;

    @Column("BIRTH_DATE")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have tried the below as well,

```
@Formula(value = "select lower(datediff(curdate(), birth_date)/365) from finances_user l where l.USER_ID = userId")
```

Below is the error stack, the field 'age' is used in the insert query. It should be a select only field.

```
DEBUG - insert into finances_user (age, BIRTH_DATE, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, EMAIL_ADDRESS, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG - could not execute statement [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'age' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have annotated your entity with `@Access(value=AccessType.PROPERTY)` which basically means that hibernate uses the getters to determine the property names that will be mapped to the columns in db. And you have a `getAge()`. Remove this annotation in order to relate only the fields annotated with `@Column` to the appropriate columns in db.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So property annotations won't work formula fields ever. Or is there any other way to do it

Comment: You can use property access type by putting `@Column` on getters. By removing `@Access` from the class, you can combine access types in entity by putting `@Column` on a field (for AccessType.FIELD) or on a getter (for AccessType.PROPERTY).